# verify public key on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

How can I verify if a ssh public key is successfully installed on a Ubuntu server?
I'm trying to unable continuos deployment and to do so I need to install the public key I got from codeship on the server.

I have copied the key I got on the server at ~/.ssh/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub
and restarted ssh but I'm still not able to deploy my app so as first debugging step I'd like to make sure the public key is properly installed on the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate test is to see if you can logon :) For now I can tell you that your key isn't in the right place. It should be appended to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (not `~/.ssh/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub`). `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should be a file, not a directory.

Please also check the permissions on the home dir, .ssh directory and authorized_keys file:

```
chmod 750 ~
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(other options are possible, but these definitely work)

And make sure all of these are owned by the user you're trying to log in as.